# Grails handle objects in select

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class like this :

```
class City {
String name;
Country country;

}
```

In the create view I want to put country as a select box like this :

```
  <g:select  id="country" optionKey="id" optionValue="countryName"
          from="${Country.list()}" name="country"  >
  </g:select>
```

What is the best way to handle the submit, so that the country is sent as an object 
(currently i receive a message :

```
    Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type com.example.Country for property country; 

nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.example.Country] for property country: 

no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

)

note : i found this matching question : [Grails select not returning the object but a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300313/grails-select-not-returning-the-object-but-a-string) but the solution didn't solve my problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Without seeing your controller code the only suggestion is to change the name of the select element to "country.id". That should automatically bind to a new instance of the country object by that id (depending on your version of Grails).

Comment: Thanks Joshua, in what version does country.id work ? I'm currently using 2.2.4

Comment: I seem to recall 2.3 has this feature, but if you are using command objects in any version from 1.3.x on this binding will work as well. Again, it depends on your controller code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Grails controller doesn't understand what to do with numeric value of `country` request parameter. Thus, in your controller you should write:

```
def country = Country.get(params.getLong('country'))
def city = new City(name: params.name, country: country)
```